# Can you just openly mix javascript with html while using html5?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

So, I'm trying to make an html5 website, and I'm trying to make a popup, "error" message using javascript, but I'm currently using html. and so when I tried

```
alert("nope wrong >:D")
```

and it didn't work. it was inside of a script tag but it still didn't work and so I'm not sure if I'm just meant to use html for that. the question overall is, do I have to use something like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

like when youre making an html website or just like

```
<!-- container -->
```

or what I need help. thx in advance for any help I get :)

Comment: Please show the code that doesn't work. If it's in a script tag and inside the head or body tags, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<!DOCTYPE html> & <!-- container -->` have nothing to do with javascript notifacations. You are correct about the `<script></script>` part. You just need to put it in a function:

```
<script>
function myAlert() {
    alert("nope wrong >:D");     
}
</script>
```

and then to call that function, use a button:

```
<button onclick="myAlert()">Click Me</button>
```

or call it on the body so when the page loads you get notified:

```
<body onload="myAlert">
```

**EDIT:** Here is a runnable code snippet

```html
<button onclick="myAlert()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function myAlert() {
    alert("nope wrong >:D");     
}
</script>
```

also, good luck!

Comment: "*You just need to put it in a function*" isn't correct, the statement in the OP will run as global code.

Comment: Thanks for the help! @InvincibleM (couldn't add another so thx RobG too)